# how to get a value from option when select (this code working for chrome)

Tags: javascript

how to get value from option

```
 <script>
    function usgsChanged(el) {
       window["display_" + el.options[el.selectedIndex].value]();
    }

    function display_1() {
       //how to get value from option
    }
 </script>
```

how to get value from option when select

```
 <select onchange="usgsChanged(this);">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="">more</option>
 <option value="">more</option>
 <option value="">more</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript).

Comment: Downvoted because duplicates abound, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function usgsChanged(option) {
    var value = option.value; //The value now resides in this variable
}
</script>  

<select onchange="usgsChanged(this);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="">more</option>
    <option value="">more</option>
    <option value="">more</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#idOfSelectTag').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  alert(value);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at internet before sanding a question. For example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp).

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function usgsChanged(el) {

   var index = el.selectedIndex;
   var selectOptions = el.options;
   var optionValue = selectOptions[index].value;
   var optionText = selectOptions[index].text;

   alert("Value is " + optionValue + " and text is " + optionText );

}
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<select onchange="usgsChanged(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="">more</option>
  <option value="">more</option>
  <option value="">more</option>
</select>
```